# Loop variable SQL query to append tables

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access, append

I have a database that has 100+ tables, all with the same header. I want to merge these tables into one. Also within the database is a table that lists all the other tables (an inventory of the database per se).

I'm looking for a way to loop the following SQL append query so `VaryingTableName` changes to follow through my inventory table:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable IN 'C:\newDBFile.accdb'
    SELECT VaryingTableName.*
    FROM VaryingTableName;
```

If there were a way to do this without the inventory table, that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most pretty solution and involves no automation but you could do:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) IN 'C:\newDBFile.accdb'
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM (
      SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
      FROM OldTable1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
      FROM OldTable2
      ...)
```